# Adding numbers to a preg_match

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\. ]*$/", $home)
```

How I can correctly add numbers 0-9 in here ?

Thanks Toni.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this -

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\. ]*$/
```

You can test this at http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

You want the text to consist of *0* or more alphabetics, digits, periods (dots), and blanks (ASCII x20)?

```
/^[a-z0-9. ]*$/i
```

is one way. Notice that you do not need to escape the period within a class. You may be able to use "shortcuts" such as \w, but the above is short and understandable. If you want *any* whitespace, including tabs, replace the blank with \s. You can add an "s" flag to treat endlines as whitespace.